# Static initialisation block in Kotlin

Tags: java, static, kotlin, initializer

What is the equivalent of a [static initialisation block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) in Kotlin?

I understand that Kotlin is designed to not have static things. I am looking for something with equivalent semantics - code is run once when the class is first loaded.

My specific use case is that I want to enable the DayNight feature from Android AppCompat library and [the instructions](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-daynight-d10f90c83e94#.4yv9vdlav) say to put some code in static initialisation block of `Application` class.

Comment: checkout this  [init-blocks kotlin vs Java](https://chetangupta.net/init-blocks/) I explained what is init block and how its invoked order plus how it's different from Java's init block, static init blocks etc

Answer (score 143, accepted):

From some point of view, [`companion object`s](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects) in Kotlin are equivalent to static parts of Java classes. Particularly, they are initialized before class' first usage, and this lets you use their `init` blocks as a replacement for Java static initializers:

```
class C {
    companion object {
        init {
            //here goes static initializer code
        }
    }
}
```

@voddan it's not an overkill, actually this is what suggested on the site of Kotlin: "A companion object is initialized when the corresponding class is loaded (resolved), matching the semantics of a Java static initializer." [Semantic difference between object expressions and declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects)

Comment: companion object is an overkill here

Comment: @voddan, OP asked about executing code before the first usage of an existing class. Solution with `object` declaration requires one to actually use it somewhere because of lazy initialization.

Comment: @voddan Would you care to explain why it's an overkill and what would are the alternatives?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I was mistaken to think you didn't cared about the class loading. The companion object is the right solution here

Comment: If static initialization is all you want to achieve, then the companion object should probably be made private or protected.

Answer (score 3):

```
companion object  { 
    // Example for a static variable
    internal var REQUEST_CODE: Int? = 500

    // Example for a static method
    fun callToCheck(value: String): String {
        // your code
    }
}
```

An object declaration inside a class can be marked with the companion keyword.And under this we can use like java static method and variable.LIke classname.methodname or classname.variablename

Comment: ADD SOME EXPLANATION TO YOUR CODE

Comment: @DerickDaniel please check now.