# How to write a package-level static initializer in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

[A previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37262468/static-initialisation-block-in-kotlin) shows how to put a static initializer inside a class using its [`companion object`](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects). I'm trying to find a way to add a static initializer at the package level, but it seems packages have no companion object.

```
// compiler error: Modifier 'companion' is not applicable inside 'file'
companion object { init { println("Loaded!") } }
fun main(args: Array<String>) { println("run!") }
```

I've tried other variations that might've made sense (`init` on its own, `static`), and I know as a workaround I can use a throwaway `val` as in

```
val static_init = {
    println("ugly workaround")
}()
```

but is there a clean, official way to achieve the same result?

---

Edit: As [@mfulton26's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38980648/how-to-write-a-package-level-static-initializer-in-kotlin/38981598#38981598) mentions, there is no such thing as a package-level function really in the JVM. Behind the scenes, the kotlin compiler is [wrapping any free functions, including `main` in a class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html). I'm trying to add a static initializer to *that* class -- the class being generated by kotlin for the free functions declared in the file.

Comment: Why not use `main` to do the initialization?

Comment: Because I picked a bad toy example. Imagine a file full of related free functions that all depend on some shared initialization. Arguably I could just wrap those in a named `object`, but a lot of the beauty of kotlin is generally not being forced to do stuff like that.

Comment: Got it. Unfortunately I don't know of a way to do that other than your workaround or a variant. e.g. `val static_init = run { println("workaround") }` or `val static_init = object { init { println("workaround") } }`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently there is no way to add code to the static constructor generated for Kotlin file classes, only top-level property initializers are getting there. This sounds like a feature request, so now there is an issue to track this: [KT-13486](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13486) Package-level 'init' blocks

Another workaround is to place initialization in top-level private/internal object and reference that object in those functions that depend on the effect of that initialization. Objects are initialized lazily, when they are referenced first time.

```
fun dependsOnState(arg: Int) = State.run {
    arg + value
}

private object State {
    val value: Int
    init {
        value = 42
        println("State was initialized")
    }
}
```

Comment: In Kotlin 1.1, you can use Kotlin Script (.kts) which will run code without needing a declaration. This is kind of similar to what the asker wants.

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned, you need a property with something that would run on initialisation:

```
val x = run {
    println("The package class has loaded")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got around it by using a Backing Property on the top-level, under the Kotlin file. [Kotlin Docs: Backing Properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-properties)

```
private var _table: Map<String, Int>? = null
public val table: Map<String, Int>
    get() {
        if (_table == null) {
            _table = HashMap() // Type parameters are inferred
           // .... some other initialising code here
        }
        return _table ?: throw AssertionError("Set to null by another thread")
    }
```

Comment: If all you need is a single, lazily-initialized value like this, Kotlin has a builtin for you: `val table: MutableMap<String, Int> by lazy(::HashMap)`